# Java unreported exception reading an input stream

Tags: java, arrays, input, compiler-errors

My code for reading an input stream of numbers and sorts them into an array, returns 
error:

unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

on             String lines = br.readLine();

```
 public int[] inputArr()  {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String lines = br.readLine();
    String[] strs = lines.trim().split("\\s+");
    int [] a = new int [strs.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
        a[i] = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
    }
    return a ;
}
```

Any help please on this?

Comment: Either you add a `throws IOException` to your method signature or you `try {} catch (IOException e) {}` it... You have those two options to *report* possible `Exception`s.

Comment: Please [Google your error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=unreported+exception+ioexception+must+be+caught+or+declared+to+be+thrown) (please click on link) before asking as most questions have been asked before, and in this case ***many*** times before.

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader.readLine()` throws an `IOException`:

```
public String readLine() throws IOException {
```

So any call to it must handle it by either:

- Surrounding with try/catch block
- Declaring that your method also throws that exception.